# Hazards (assembly)

Tags: assembly, processor

I have been given this code and I need to identify the RAW, WAR and WAW hazards.

```
1. MOV R3, R7
2. LD R8, (R3)
3. ADD R3, R3, 4
4. LOAD R9, (R3)
5. BNE R8, R9, L3
```

I think that there are RAW hazards between line 1 & 2, 1 & 3 and 4 & 5. I can't spot any other hazards but I believe that there are more. Would anyone be able to help me and explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most problems are considered when concurrent execution happens and to improve performance instructions are not executed in order. If `BNE` modifies the contents of R8 (in ARM it just modifies PC with a label or overwrites it with a register without modifying it) then the hazards I could find where:

1 & 2: RAW (You got this one)

3 & 4: RAW (You would load the contents of 4 bytes before the contents you want assuming it is byte addressable and R3 does have the address you wanted from previous instructions)

4 & 5: RAW (You got this one)

1 & 3: RAW, WAW (You got this one but WAW can also happen as you are writing into R3 and reading its value too in 3.)

2 & 5: WAW (If `BNE` modifies `R8` then 2 and 5 can cause and WAW)

2 & 3: WAR (If 3 goes first then 2 would have the wrong value)